# How can I make a visual countdown timer in Spritekit which fills up when user gets a score?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, sprite-kit

What would be the most efficient way to make something like these visual countdown timers using `SpriteKit`, which will get updated once the user gets the score, and once they're empty, which means the time's run out, the user loses the game? The images below is from Timeberman game, Thank you.

[image]

Comment: These types of questions are not meant for SO,  perhaps try looking for a tutorial on matters like these.  If you can reword this to be a  specific question that can yield a specific answer, then it would fall in line with SO.

Comment: I have searched enough for tutorials, Couldn't find any straightforward solution and their source codes cost like $50, I just need an efficient and simple strategy not the code. @Knight0fDragon

Comment: Try looking at loading bar tutorials, but you do it in reverse